# What is LENCE] in Amazon Transcribe

Tags: amazon-web-services, voice-recognition, amazon-transcribe

[Edited]

So, I used Amazon Transcribe (https://aws.amazon.com/transcribe), by clicking `create jobs`

Then, I did a job setting thing (in `Amazon Transcribe > Transcription jobs > Create transcription job`).

Used a Japanese mp3 file and set `Speaker identification` to `Speaker identification` and `Alternative results` to `Enabled`.

Finally when I see the result, `LENCE]` sometimes appears in it.

What does it mean?

I could not find any explanation for this in AWS website.

Thanks

Comment: Can you possibly edit your question and provide more information so that we can try to reproduce this situation? Or at least tell us more about what you are doing (which commands on what data) and where you are seeing this message?

Comment: Cheers, I edited my question. I hope it got more informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks a little bit like the word `SILENCE`, which might indicate a gap in the conversation.

From [Channel Identification - Amazon Transcribe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/how-channel-id.html):

> Speakers' utterances are ordered by their start time. An utterance is a unit of speech on the audio channel that is **typically separated from other utterances by silence**. If an utterance on one channel overlaps one on another channel, Amazon Transcribe orders them in the transcription by their start times. Utterances that overlap in the input audio don't overlap in the transcription output.